# Gitlab job does not extends another job correctly

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to use a common configuration for two jobs in my gitlab ci pipeline.
Purpose is to trigger end-to-end testing with firebase both locally and remotely.

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
before_script:
  - npm i
  - npm i -g firebase-tools

cache:
  key:
    files:
      - package-lock.json
  paths:
    - ~/node_modules

.e2e:
  stage: 'test'
  image: cypress/base:16.13.0
  script:
    - npm i -g firebase-tools
    - apt update
    - apt -y install default-jre # For firebase emulators
    - apt -y install default-jdk # For firebase emulators
    - firebase use test --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"
    - npm ci

e2e:local:
  extends: .e2e
  script:
    - npm run e2e:local
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - .npm
      - cache/Cypress
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - cypress/videos
      - cypress/screenshots
    expire_in: 5 day
```

The problem here is that when the job e2e:local runs, it throws an error, because it does not find firebase command, which means the "npm i -g firebase-tools" command of the .e2e job is not triggered.

Where am I wrong ?
Thanks for help

Comment: `e2e:local`’s `script` _overwrites_ `.e2e`’s `script`. Maybe use `before_script` in `.e2e`?

Comment: Is there a way to run both scripts or an equivalent ? Maybe use a before_script in .e2e ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use extends in a job, and then the step 'script', what it does is overwrite the job you are extending.
What you can do is use the after_script step at e2e:local:

```
e2e:local:
  extends: .e2e
  after_script:
    - npm run e2e:local
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - .npm
      - cache/Cypress
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - cypress/videos
      - cypress/screenshots
    expire_in: 5 day
```

---

Another solution could be to make use of !reference

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags

```
e2e:local:
  extends: .e2e
  script:
    - !reference [.e2e, script]
    - npm run e2e:local
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - .npm
      - cache/Cypress
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - cypress/videos
      - cypress/screenshots
    expire_in: 5 day
```